# Blown Thermostat Twice and Dead Transformer

Tags: hvac, thermostat, transformer

A year ago, I had a brand new smart thermostat that caused the A/C fuse to keep blowing.  I replaced the thermostat with a duplicate, swapped the fuse out and everything has been fine.   Now a year later, my AC fuse again blew.  I checked the thermostat on another ac in the house and it blew that fuse too.  I replaced both fuses.  Now the AC with the problem will not supply any power out of the 24v side of the transformer, as tested with a multimeter.  I've ordered a new transformer and a replacement thermostat for the third time.

Is it coincidence it's the same unit and I've now had 2 bad thermostats?   It is possible the transformer has been bad this whole time and finally gave out, taking the thermostat with it?   This AC is not even 2 years old but the company that installed it is pretty poor and won't stand behind their install.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include make & model of both the thermostat and the AC unit.

Comment: Yes, we'll need to know the make and model of the various things involved here.  Also, when you say "A/C fuse", I take it you're referring to the (often automotive-type) fuse on the low voltage side of the transformer, typically found in the indoor unit/air handler?

Comment: it's possible for a mis-wired thermostat to damage the transformer.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much can guarantee either you've wired up your thermostat wrong, or that you chose a thermostat whose current draw on the connection to the A/C unit  exceeds the A/C port's rated capability.
Consider checking the manuals.
Then see if you can power the thermostat off a different source, such as a local DC supply, rather than hanging it off the A/C block.